# AngularJS - Disable $exceptionHandler

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't want $exceptionHandler to handle any exceptions - I want them to propegate up to the browser (primarily for IE testing in Visual Studio).

I'd tried overriding $exceptionHandler and simply rethrowing the error, which gives me the 10 iterations of $digest error (which makes sense).

How do I shut it off completely?

**EDIT**

Unfortunately rethrowing the error doesn't solve the issue - IE only knows the error from the rethrow and not from source.

Comment: Was your overridden $exceptionHandler similar to the one provided in [ngMock](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L247)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research, this isn't possible.  Angular catches their errors and then calls the exception handler explicitly - in many cases it does not just let the error propagate.

Comment: This is one of the most frustrating parts of angularjs. I can't understand why it's even part of the library.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/docs/api/ng.%24exceptionHandler), it's possible:

```
angular.module('exceptionOverride', []).factory('$exceptionHandler', function () {
    return function (exception, cause) {
        exception.message += ' (caused by "' + cause + '")';
        throw exception;
    };
});
```

> This example will override the normal action of $exceptionHandler, to
>   make angular exceptions fail hard when they happen, instead of just
>   logging to the console.

Comment: Thanks mems - the problem with this is that it still code capture the error and rethrows it from the override.  When that happens you loose the original stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Try throwing the exception inside a `window.setTimeout` (not `$timeout`) delayed execution, this would allow you to escape the `$digest` black hole. But not sure it will preserve the stack-trace in IE.